# createQuery with JPQL hangs

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

When I call createQuery(String, Class) application hangs. Hibernate last INFO is "Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory" but then nothing happens.  Here is the code:

```
public User getUserByLogin(String username) {
    String queryString = "SELECT u FROM USERS u WHERE u.USERNAME = :username";
    TypedQuery<User> query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString, User.class);
    return query.setParameter("username", username).getSingleResult();
}
```

It hangs on `TypedQuery<User> query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString, User.class);`

But what is funny, when I change method body like this:

```
public User getUserByLogin(String username) {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> userRoot = criteriaQuery.from(User.class);
    criteriaQuery.select(userRoot).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(userRoot.get("username"), username));
    TypedQuery<User> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    return query.getSingleResult();
}
```

it works fine. Same environment, just different body of methos. What Am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why `FROM USERS u` instead of `FROM USER u`

Comment: USERS is database table name.

Comment: Yes, then that is what wrong. With JPQL, you need to query on entity name instead of table name.